# How to allow chat agents to watch each others chats?

Tags: chat

Is it possible to give chat agents viewing access to each other's chats? Like if Agent A is in a chat, is there a way Agent B can watch as it's happening? If yes, what needs to be done to allow that?

I apologize if this is a simple/dumb question, I haven't been able to find an answer to it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to let one agent view another agent's ongoing chat. If another agent's intervention is required, they can [Send a Chat Conferencing Request](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_conference_in_chats.htm&type=5) following below steps:

> 1. While you’re chatting with a customer, click Chat Conferencing Icon.
>    2.Select the skill group of the agents that you want to transfer into the chat.
> 2. Select whether to send the conference request to all agents with that skill or to a specific agent.
> 3. Click Conference. If the agent accepts the conference request, you see a notification in the chat log, and that agent can start chatting.
>    If the agent declines the request, you see a notification above the
>    chat log. The customer receives a notification when an agent joins or
>    leaves a conference.
> 4. If you decide to exit the conference, click Leave Conversation. When the other agents leave the conference, agents see a notification
>    in the chat log. The last agent in the conference must click End
>    Conversation.

Note that the user to be on the Chat Conference should have view access to the Chat Transcript object.

Alternately, the [Omni supervisors](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omni-channel-lex/omni-supervisor) have the ability to monitor Service Cloud Voice transcripts, and chat messages between agents and customers, and send helpful messages that only the support agent sees.

Related [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZprUAF/allow-livemessage-messaging-to-be-monitored-in-omni-supervisor)